# Send ansible job output as an email

Tags: email, ansible

Can Ansible tower job output be send as an email once the job is completed?
I am able to send email once each task is completed using the `mail` module. But I am not able to send email after the job is completed.

Answer (score 0):

You need ansible notifier to do that. See [this](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/notifications.html#notification-types) page.

Comment: Notifier will only send the job status as output, I need to send the whole job summary output even if the tasks fails or not.